# Gaussian measure in Hilbert Space, proof there exist a polinomian

Tags: functional-analysis

Over a measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ consider the Gaussian measure defines by $\mu(B) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{B}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Let $H = L^{2}(\mu)$

show that for every integer n, there exists a unique polynomial $\widehat{P}_ {n}$ of degree $n$ such that $\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}) = (-1)^{n}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\widehat{P}_{n}$
and for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ if you define $P_{n} = \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\widehat{P}_{n}$ ,then  $(P_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is ortonormal family in $H$

I really try to find the proof , using different theorems like risk , but i couldn´t , any help i will appreciate it

Comment: Use induction. Can you do it for $n=1$?

Comment: this dont tell me nothing

Comment: Just start differentiating $e^{-\frac{x^2}2}$. You will obtain the polynomial $\hat P_1$.